# Having trouble with multiple Jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen the posts about the no conflict but I'm not very code savvy and can't figure it out alone. I'm having trouble making two libraries work together.

At the top I have the 1.9.1 library which controls a news ticker, and a carousel. Near the bottom there is a library 1.6.1, which controls a Dribbble feed. If I remove 1.6.1 everything but the dribbble feed works, and if I remove the 1.9.1 the dribbble feed is the only thing that works. I uploaded the website for you guys to check out. If you could edit my code to make it work that would be amazing, I don't have much knowledge of jquery.

This version has a working dribbble feed at the very bottom
http://michaelcullenbenson.com/MichaelCullenBenson.com/index.html

and this version has a broken feed and everything else works.
http://michaelcullenbenson.com/MichaelCullenBenson.com/index2.html

Help would be AMAZING as the dribbble feed is the last element I'm trying to finish on my homepage and I'll be able to move on.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    $('#news').innerfade({
                        animationtype: 'slide',
                        speed: 600,
                        timeout: 6000,
                        type: 'random',
                        containerheight: '1em'
                    });


            });
    </script>

        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="utilcarousel-files/utilcarousel/jquery.utilcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="utilcarousel-files/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>





        <script>
            $(function() {


                $('#fullwidth').utilCarousel({
                    breakPoints : [[600, 1], [800, 2], [1000, 3], [1300, 4],],
                    mouseWheel : false,
                    rewind : true,
                    autoPlay : true,
                    pagination : false
                });

                $('#fullwidth2').utilCarousel({
                    breakPoints : [[600, 1], [800, 2], [1000, 3], [1300, 4],],
                    mouseWheel : false,
                    rewind : true,
                    autoPlay : true,
                    pagination : false
                });

            });
        </script>

   <script>     
        $(document).ready(function() {
var movementStrength = 25;
var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
$("#aboutarea").mousemove(function(e){
          var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
          var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
          var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
          var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
          $('#aboutarea').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
});
});

    </script>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dribbble.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#user').dribbble({
            player: 'MCBDesign', 
            total: 1
        }); 
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: simple rule of thumb, only load jQuery once in page and load it before all dependednt plugins and code

Comment: Tn the index2.html example I removed the second library 1.6.1 and it broke. That was actually the first thing I did but for some reason the dribbble one breaks when the 1.6.1 is removed.

http://michaelcullenbenson.com/MichaelCullenBenson.com/index2.html

Comment: @charlietfl is right. I would recommend including only the newer of the two versions of jQuery, and the jQuery migrate plugin for the appropriate older version on jQuery.

Comment: Lol i did that in my index2.html version, but it didnt work. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, remember that it is never recommended to use two seperate versions of jQuery on the same page.  However, if you absolutely have to, you can use the method below to make it work.

On to the explanation:

It looks like you do not quite grasp how jQuery no-conflict works.

The idea of no conflict is not as simple as loading one version of jQuery along with its scripts, then including another version of jQuery and its scripts.. its easiest to assign the older version its own "namespace" (which is really just a huge function) while letting the newer version use the default "namespace" (which is jQuery **or** $)

**NOTE:** jQuery normally takes on the "namespace" of $, which is why you see lines of code like this: $.each **or** $("#selector") instead of jQuery.each **or** jQuery("selector")

**NOTE:** remove the spaces in < script > in the code below (SO does not like script tags apparently)

To dive into your specific case, you need to load jQuery version 1.9.1 first as you would normally:

> < script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" >< /script > (You should really load this from google cdn, [here is why](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/))

Then, include the older version of jQuery, 1.6.1.

> < script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" >< /script >

After that comes the noconflict part.  Include a one line script as follows:

> < script > var $j6 = jQuery.noConflict(); < /script >

This will set the 1.6.1 version to the $j6 "namespace" and hold the 1.9.1 version in the normal $ "namespace" which will allow you to target the specific version like so:

> $j6('#user').dribble() and $('#news').innerfade()

Now you should have 2 seperate versions of jquery running side by side.

You may need to do a mass find/replace on the dribble plugin (and any other plugins using the 1.6.1 library).. replacing all instances of jQuery (or $) with $j6.

Note this may not be the absolute best solution.. and I am no expert in no-conflict, but it has always worked for me.

Comment: Holy Crap man, you're a life saver. Totally worked, also, thanks for the tip about the google cdn, I don't know much about jquery, so knowing that it helps so much for loading times is great. I've see stuff like < script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ before in plugins and didn't exactly know what it meant, just that the file was hosted somewhere else.

THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN!

Comment: I'd give you an up vote, but I don't even have 15 reputation. :)

Comment: That totally worked and the other elements are working again, along with the dribbble feed, but my lightbox broke. When I remove the 1.6.1 library it works again. I'm not really sure why thats related.

The only jquery that is used for the lightbox is 
jquery.magnific-popup.js

I tried switching the $ with $j6 like before, but it didn't work. All I know is that it is specifically effected by that 1.6.1 library.

Here is a link to the updated website. If you weren't aware, the lightbox is in the carousel images.

http://michaelcullenbenson.com/MichaelCullenBenson.com/index2.html#